# video streaming

Tags: networking, network-programming, video-streaming

I am designing an application for streaming video.I have developed a model in which a server wait for incoming request.The server it self is serving to a good number of clients and it can't afford to serve any more clients.Now when the new connection comes,the server chooses from among it's clients a candidate client who will serve the request of the incoming client.Now the thing is that this choice should be very intelligent.Now I am using various heuristic like bandwidth of the selected client,it's location,distance from the requesting client to come at a decision.Now my question is,IS THERE AVAILABLE ANY TOOL TO FIND OUT BANDWIDTH,LOCATION of a host,and DISTANCE(my be in hop number)?for hop number I can use traceroute but that will be  too expensive as it take long time sending reply from every intermediate router.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Retag it with network-realted tags. It's not a video-streaming question.

Answer (score 1):

Use traceroute to find number of hops.

Use dnsstuff APIs to find location.

Do some TCP packet exchange to understand bandwidth of a client. You will get highest and lowest bandwidth client relatively.

If client is going to serve older video, take amount of data as consideration (i.e. Bigger the content, higher the change of streaming correct data)

Comment: thanks for the reply.In fact I have already been considering these options,but I was looking for a better alternative if possible.Is there other alternative available?
thanks again for the reply.